# Using PHP-DI for Wordpress Plugin using PSR-4?

Tags: wordpress, php-di

I'm writing a wordpress plugin using the https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate template and I'm trying to configure PHP-DI (http://php-di.org/) to handle injection of classes across my plugin.

My composer config is this

```
{
  "name" : "emeraldjava/bhaa_wordpress_plugin",
  "description" : "bhaa_wordpress_plugin",
  "type" : "wordpress-plugin",
  "require": {
    "php-di/php-di": "^6.0"
  },
  "autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
      "BHAA\\" : "src"
    }
  }
}
```

In my Main.php class I'm creating the PHP-DI Container object and i'm expecting that autowiring should take effect, so I don't
 need to register a lot of objects in the addDefinitions() method.

```
use DI\ContainerBuilder;

use function DI\autowire;
use function DI\create;

class Main {

    public function __construct() {
        // This is the current manual initialisation of the Loader class. I want to be able to inject this object reference
        $this->loader = new utils\Loader();
        $this->buildContainer();
    }

    private function buildContainer() {
        $builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        $builder->addDefinitions([
            // I add the object definition to the container here
            'loader' => $this->loader,
        ]);
        $this->container = $builder->build();
    }    
}
```

I have a new class called LeagueCPT where i'd like to inject the Loader object reference

```
namespace BHAA\front\cpt;

use BHAA\utils\Loader;

class LeagueCPT {

    private $loader;

    public function __construct(Loader $loader) {
        // i'm expecting that Loader will be injected here but it's null
    }
}
```

In the original code I would have manually created the LeagueCPT and passed the reference manually, like this

```
class Main {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->leagueCpt = new front\cpt\LeagueCPT($this->loader);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting now that I should be able to call the Container to create me a new object for League with the correct constructor injected

```
class Main {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->leagueCpt = $this->getContainer()->get(LeagueCPT);
    }
}
```

but in each case, i can't see the LeagueCPT getting initialised by PHP-DI. I'd appreciate any suggestion on how i can correctly configure the DI system in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Autowiring works by checking out the type-hints of parameters. In your constructor you have `Loader $loader`.

You need to put your loader in the PHP-DI config under the `BHAA\utils\Loader` key, not just `loader` (PHP-DI will not guess things magically with just `loader`).

So replace `'loader' => $this->loader,` by `\BHAA\utils\Loader::class => $this->loader,` and you should be good.